# What is happening here? Is Unity crashing?

Tags: unity

Hopefully someone can enlighten me about a baffling and frustrating issue!

Sometimes when I am doing an installation or a removal, something weird happens. All the open windows disappear, and I see my desktop wallpaper. Then all the windows reappear, but they have no menu bar, so I can't close them. The bar at the top of the screen (with the clock and so on) has also disappeared, as indeed has the Unity Launcher. When this happens, all I can do is wait for the process to finish, and then use CTRL+ALT+DELETE to log out of Ubuntu, then log back in again. Only seems to happen if I am doing updates or installing/removing software.

What exactly is happening here, has anyone else ever seen this, and perhaps most importantly, is there a way to stop this from happening?

**My machine:**
Dell Inspiron 530
ATI Radeon HD6670 graphics card (running the latest driver)
RAM: 4GB

*And I'm running 64 bit.*

There isn't really a "step-by-step" way to reproduce the issue because I can never predict exactly *when* it will occur. Usually I'm installing a program through Software Center or update manager, maybe running other things in the background - Terminal, Firefox etc. - and then everything flickers, all the windows disappear and then come back with no menu bars.

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron 530, but I have an ATI Radeon HD6670 graphics card and I am running the latest driver.

Comment: 4GB, and I'm running 64 bit so I actually DO get 4GB

Comment: Ok desgua, I will try that.

Comment: That replicated the error!

Comment: I did a "clean up" of my messages. Resume: I asked for machine specifications, then suggest run compiz --replace in a terminal to catch any error message. Did you get some?

Comment: Hi desgua, didn't see any errors, but running compiz --replace did EXACTLY the thing I said was happening!

Comment: Ok desgua, I ran compiz --replace, and all my windows disappeared, but they all came back with menu bars and Unity Launcher, as they should be.  The only error that I saw in terminal was this:


_ERROR 2013-05-25 01:14:57 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed_

Comment: When you run the command you will have to wait to Compiz reload all the plugins, then all should come back. Until here we don't get any clue. You will have to use your computer and when it really breaks you can search for an error message. Got it?

Comment: But how do I search for an error message when the error actually occurs?  I can't even open any new programs when that happens!

Comment: So you can not change the focus of the windows to see the terminal when that happens? Looks like a compiz crash.

Comment: OK so it is a compiz crash.  What could be causing it and how do I stop it?

Comment: I think we could find a solution if we could narrow down this bug. My suggestion: open Compiz-Settings-Manager and try to disable some plugins (I would start with animations for close, open, minimize, etc). May be with some plugins disabled this bug wont occur. Regards.

Comment: Another suggestion: Try the radeon videodriver instead of the catalyst/fglrx driver. If the problem disappears it was a videodriver problem. It is quite common that proprietary drives can be flakey from time to time and compiz is very sensitive to that. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Removing_the_proprietary_fglrx_driver) link might help to change driver.

Answer (score 2):

To restart your shell manually after such a crash (this *is* a crash), you could instead of logging out go to a virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+F1), login there, issue the following command:

```
(DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace &)
```

You should first clean the environment like `killall compiz & killall unity` since stray processes of Unity might remain even after the crash.

Oh, and to return to the graphical environment, alt+F7 (+optional ctrl)